# firebase phone auth sms contains extra characters not present in template

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Used Firebase Phone Auth in my Android app.
The sms contains extra characters `ntEc9wgP0/J` at the end of the template.

Tried setting `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().setLanguageCode("en")`

`Template language` is set to `English` in Firebase console.
What can be the reason behind this?

This is my sms code template in firebase console.

`%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.`

Firebase Phone Auth itself is working absolutely fine. What am I missing here?

EDIT : [image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjyrC.png)

EDIT2 : [how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUnue.png)

Comment: Please Provide Some Screenshots of your problem. it would be helpful

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna added image of problem. As you can see the letters ntEc9wgP0/J should not be there in the sms.

Comment: i have the same issue, did you resolve it? @ChandanPednekar

Comment: @JürgenGunz no. i did not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the same issue in my case auto retrieval hash was only coming when otp sms length was below 53 characters so i contacted firebase support team regarding this .

**As per firebase support team** "If this is Android traffic then this is the appended auto-retrieval hash. We use the  [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) . So this extra characters are expected because these are the auto-retrieval hash"

** To Increase the character length you can change your app name on the google console.

Comment: I'll try increasing the message to more than 53 characters tonight and check.

Comment: You can change your app name  to increase  characters length .

Comment: increased message length from 48 characters to 81 and now the hash does not show.

Comment: Where Do I have to change APP name?

Comment: @RahulSaliya if your app is published on the play store then go to google console and change your app name there. The app name is retrieved from the play store/app store once the app is live in the store.

Comment: Changing the app name of the published app on the google play store takes 24 hours so plan accordingly.